# Snap to inventory slot problem bge

Tags: game-engine

So I've started using Blender Game Engine again to try to make an inventory system COMPLETELY out of Logic bricks :O

So far, it is going very good!

[image: 15 x 3 slots, with 3 different items (Green, Blue and Red)]

But when I tried to make the items snap to the slots when placing it, I came to a halt...

I have no idea how to do it by using logic bricks! I've tried giving it a Constraint when it collides with one of the slots but that gets EXTREMELY complex extremely fast, and doesn't even work some times!

[image: The complex setup for snapping...]

I am desperate for advice from anyone! Please help, and keep in mind that I'm trying to use as less as possible scripting!

Comment: oh. wow. this would be easy with python, but you may need a logic brick master like @X-27 to help if you want only logic bricks.

Comment: How do you even keep track of the logic bricks you already have?? The connecting lines are so clumped together...

Comment: So many collision sensors. I really suggest to look for a simpler solution. The maintenance would be easier too. You could focus on a single slot and replicated it by using instances.

Comment: I am aware of the complexity, thank you very much :) Maybe I should try python... any scripting that could help??

Comment: I suggest to open a thread on blenderartist to get some design feedback. You do not need to do everything in python (that would be silly). Just the dynamic parts, such as storage, object identification. Your inventory will still need game objects as interface to the user.